# Double click on Google Chrome Action listener

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension but unable to get double click on a browser tab working.

I looked the Chrome.tab API [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) but unable to find any such function. Is there any way we can have a method to detect double click on a tab.

Comment: There's no way to detect even a *single* click on a tab, as far as I know. The [`onActivated`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated) handler can tell when the active tab is changed, but no way to know if that happened via click or Ctrl+Tab.

Comment: The point of Chrome's security model is that extensions don't have access to the entire browser, only what those APIs provide.

Comment: Okay. I never thought this method won't be available.